# Logstash ignores config file or doesnt see log file

Tags: logstash

I have a `/etc/logstash/conf.d` file which looks like this

```
input {

  file {
        path => "/tmp/test_messages.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }

}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

then I start my Logstash like this

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d
```

get the message

```
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Pipeline main started
```

but then nothing happens. When I do

```
echo ashdkashkdasd >> /tmp/test_messages.txt
```

logstash doesnt output anything. What's wrong?

Comment: does logstash have permission to read the file in /tmp?

Comment: try adding `sincedb_path` as `/dev/null`

Comment: Also add a new line at the end of your log

Comment: @pandaadb yes, when I run logstash as `sudo` the same happens.

Comment: @MrunalPagnis added, thanks. Didn't help though http://prnt.sc/burbs4

Comment: @baudsp didnt help either

Comment: I just tried this locally and this definitely should be working just fine. Try replacing your file input with stdin. If stdin is working, then you most definitely have a permissions issue and logstash does not read the file. Check /var/log/logstash (presumably) for any messages/errors

Comment: @pandaadb yes, stdin works perfectly, thanks a lot!